# use localstorage instead of database to avoid requests to the server

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am creating an application in which the user can post information as well as choose as a favorite the publication of someone else, when the user performs any of these actions I keep the necessary information in the in the database, specifically in a document where the information linked to the user is found (name, surname, telephone number, etc.).

so when the user logging in the page I get all that information with a single query and I keep it in the LOCALSTOAGE and reduce the queries in the database, then in a different section you can see the publications you have created as well as the ones you have marked as favorites, very similar to what we commonly see in an online store

I'm using angular 6, noje.js and mongoDB. My question is the following:

Is this a correct and effective way to do it?
Should I save it in the database and then perform the corresponding query to obtain it?

shows a screenshot of local storage for explicit use:

[image]
As you can see I also save the token that I use to authenticate the user's queries and obviously I do not show your password I would like your opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never should consider localStorage as an alternative to the database.

At some point, you might have a huge amount of data and your browser would crash to load them.

Bring the data you required from the server.

For some minimum and temporary amount of data, you can consider localStorage. Don't bring all the data in a single query to save database operation. Databases are built to do that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation